# Remove temporary files in chrome, without losing access to websites

Tags: chrome, cache

My chrome (PortableApps) profile takes above 1Gb.
I found no way of cleaning the cache (to the point of freeing a large fraction of the space taken), without losing access to websites, e.g.

Is that possible, without syncing Chrome?

I would guess it is.

Could I simply empty these directories with `rm`?

```
205M    ./Default/Application Cache
644M    ./Default/Code Cache
```

Answer (score 0):

It is where the Google chrome application cache is stored, you can [turn sync on in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277) before deleting those folders.

Comment: Can I remove those dirs without syncing, and without losing my login info on websites (I want to avoid syncing, if possible)? 
It looks strange to me that, at least a directory named Code Cache, would contain data related to websites login.
Application Cache is a more dubious name.